# error with new moveit_core 0.6.11

Tags: ros, moveit, planning-scene

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros indigo

ubuntu 14.04 trusty

i have just installed moveit_core-indigo-devel 0.6.11. as i was facing the same error in "constraint_samplers::IKConstraintSampler::callIK with assertion validate(state) failed."

i am now getting the error:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libmoveit_planning_scene_monitor.so: undefined reference to `planning_scene::PlanningScene::PlanningScene(boost::shared_ptr<moveit::core::RobotModel> const&, boost::shared_ptr<collision_detection::World>)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/jaysin/ros/ws_clam/devel/lib/hal_main/arms_server] Error 1
make[1]: *** [clam/hal_main/CMakeFiles/arms_server.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

i have tried different things with my link libraries in CMakeLists.txt but no success. the library "libmoveit_planning_scene.so" and it's header "planning_scene.h" are both there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196969/error-with-new-moveit_core-0.6.11/) by [jay75](https://answers.ros.org/users/5740/jay75/) on ROS Answers with karma: 259 on 2014-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved on the mailing list, issue was that moveit-ros-* packages are out of date. ABI compatibility is not really been kept on ROS things < 1.0 (and often isn't so well kept on things > 1.0), so I would always recommend updating all ROS packages. One easy way to do this is:

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install ros-indigo-*
```

Which will upgrade all previously installed ros-indigo packages.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1